# Defining large data sets in Python before storing them in a database

Tags: python, json, data-structures, dataset

I'm composing a large data set that later on will be parsed and added programmatically using Python to the database (PostgresSQL backend through SQLAlchemy).

So, 2 questions:

1. What is the best way to compose, define and store such data before it's being inserted to DB? Is this the right way to do it? Someone still needs to compose such JSON-a-like structures, which is tedious, maybe completely different approach should be taken. I'm open to any suggestions.
2. These data structures tend to be really big (10k lines per one object). That's why I'm trying to put every single object in the separate Python file and import them later by the import script. Since this data is defined as a *const* with the specific name, how I'm supposed to import it in another module, without knowing its name in advance? I can import *, but this doesn't solve the problem, since I still need to know the const name to start working with it.

Thanks for your answers and propositions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I've found answers to my questions myself. Here there are:

1. Simple JSON format with further validation using [jsonschema](http://json-schema.org) should be utilized
2. It should be JSON file, not Python with const inside. The data inside JSON files should be self-descriptive, so just iterating through all JSON files with additional parsing will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the end you will probably want to flatten the datastructure for the table and turn each different configuration into its own row in the table, like so:

```
Table Cars

  maker  model  generation  year  body_type  fuel_type  drivetrain_type  gearbox_type  aspiration_type  displacement  cylinders  power_rating  modification
citroen     C5           I  2000   liftback     petrol              FWD            AT               NA           3.0          6           207
citroen     C5           I  2000   liftback     petrol              FWD            MT               NA           3.0          6           207
```

With either another table containing the display names

```
Table Display_Names

      id         display_name
 citroen              Citroen
      C5                   C5
       I                    I
liftback             Liftback
  petrol               Petrol
     FWD    Front Wheel Drive
      AT            Automatic
      MT               Manual
      NA  Naturally Aspirated
```

or the table directly containing the display names.

So probably your JSON data should reflect this structure, if possible.

Comment: This isn't exactly answers my questions. BTW, my SQL database has separate tables for models, generations, fuel types, engines, etc. These tables are mostly connected using relations (one-to-many) and this part is completely fine. However,  the data defined in Python, which is not yet in the DB - don't.

Comment: @none32 Well, in that case you should have mentioned your database layout, instead of asking what is the best data structure to put it into a DB afterwards. But yes, I know that this is at best a partial answer.

Comment: From my point of view, the database layout is irrelevant here. It is already there and won't change. The question was about the most optimal way of defining given data in Python data structures, so it can be imported into DB later on, using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @none32: Yes, and that best datastructure (in Python) might depend on your already existing datastructure (in the DB). But I don't know enough about this to give you more of an answer than this. Someone more knowledgeable needs to answer.

Comment: I would kindly disagree with your statement. I think that you are mixing up 2 different things: database models in Python (inherited from db.Models) and just a way of data definition and representation.